# Error sending mails on Google App Engine with PHP

Tags: google-app-engine, lumen, php-7.2

I have Lumen running on a Google App Engine instance and everything is great, except sending mail. The standard PHP `mail()` returns `false` no matter what I try and I can't find errors in the log.

```
/**
 * Deliver an email
 * 
 * @param string $to_email
 * @param string $body
 * @param string $subject
 * 
 * @return bool
 */
static public function send($to_email, $body, $subject)
{
    $headers = 'From: myemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: myemail+punkr@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: Punkr/1.0';
    return mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, it seems that GAE can't find sendmail. I have tried setting sendmail_path to normal locations, but it is not found. Anyone know of the correct location?

The reason I didn't spot this earlier was that the error output is just:

"sh: 1: -t: not found"

Comment: I ended up using external mailer (SendGrid) instead. I suspect this is purely a PHP 7.2 issue on GAE. I will circle back if other answers appear because I would rather not use external provider.

Answer (score 0):

Your send mail not working could be because of different reasons:

1. The sender's email ID should be added as an owner in the AppEngine project or use service account ID as the sender. ***[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/#who_can_send_mail)***
2. If above doesn't work for you, you can try an alternative approach.

   ```
    use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

    try {
        $message = new Message();
        $message->setSender('from@example.com');
        $message->addTo('to@example.com');
        $message->setSubject('Example email');
        $message->setTextBody('Hello, world!');
        $message->send();
        echo 'Mail Sent';
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        echo 'There was an error';
       }
   ```

*Hope this answers your question!!!!!*

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but it doesn't help much. The problem is due to the fact that sendmail binary is not found. And the alternative approach also use PHPs mail() in the end and therefore sendmail. :/

Comment: Can you show the whole traceback of your error bcz `use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;` this should have worked for you.